Is shear transformation a linear mapping?
Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix}$, $B = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2\end{bmatrix}$ be vectors of set $V$ over $R^2$
Let $f(X) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & m \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} X$ be the horiz shear transformation, where $m$ is constant $ \in R $
One can show that:
$f(A) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & m \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 + ma_2 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix}$
$f(B) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & m \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 + mb_2 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix}$
Thus:
$f(A + B) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & m \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_1 + b_1 \\ a_2 + b_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 + b_1 + m(a_2 + b_2) \\ a_2 + b_2 \end{bmatrix} = f(A) + f(B) (1)$
$f(n A) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & m \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} n a_1 \\ n a_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} na_1 + mna_2 \\ na_2 \end{bmatrix} = nf(A)$, where $n$ is constant $ \in R $ $ (2)$
From $(1), (2)$, it is clearly that shear is a linear transformation
My question is why this page on Wikipedia states that shear mapping is affine transformation? Aren't those two different things?

For any matrix $A\in M_{n,m}(\Bbb R)$, the map $$\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n,\quad X\mapsto AX$$ is linear. This is a special case of the bilinearity of the matrix product. I understand that it does not answer your question. It is only a remark which makes a large part of your post unnecessary (from "One can show that" to "clearly that shear is a linear transformation").
